# Is it possible to generate response times comparison graphs for few samples which are common across two threads in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I have two thread groups in one test plan.

I have similar samples under each thread groups. Lets there are 10 similar samples like SampleRequest1 , SampleRequest2 .....SampleRequest10.

I am looking for a way to generate comparison graphs between respective samples response times in threads.

Response Time for SampleRequest1 Thread Group1 vs Response Time SampleRequest2 Thread Group2.

Can someone enlighten me on this? How can achieve this? If there are any reference documents please share.

Comment: Please let me know if any additional information required

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use [Filter Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/) on your .jtl results file to generate 2 separate .jtls:

   - one having `Thread Group1 - SampleRequest1` results
   - another one containing `Thread Group2 - SampleRequest2` results

   Once you have 2 separate results files for "interesting" samplers you can combine them into one using [Merge Results tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/MergeResults/)

   Both tools can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)
2. You can use [BM.Sense](https://sense.blazemeter.com/) results analysis service, just upload your .jtl results file there and you will be able to compare whatever requests you want by any metric on the `Composite Timeline` tab:

   [image: BlazeMeter Sense Composite Timeline]